# How to disable typography in github pages?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

Is there a way to disable typography in github pages?

For instance I want `'...'` in the output instead of `‘…’` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [Jekyll uses Kramdown](https://www.markdownguide.org/tools/jekyll/), that parser will, as documented in [syntax / typographic symbols](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#typographic-symbols), replace `...` with an [ellipsis](https://practicaltypography.com/ellipses.html) (like this `…`)

Maybe you can try and use the [`typographic_symbols`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/markdown/) Jekyll option which comes from [issue 472](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/issues/472)

```
--typographic_symbols "{hellip: ...}"
```

If not, you would need to [define a filter](https://www.sylvaindurand.org/improving-typography-on-jekyll/), to replace `{{ content }}` with what you want.

```
{% assign t = t | replace: '…', '...' }
```

The [OP Mikhail Morfikov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3015317/mikhail-morfikov) also suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61044379/how-to-disable-typography-in-github-pages/61044687#comment107996606_61044687):

```
kramdown:
  ...
  typographic_symbols: { hellip: ... , mdash: --- , ndash: -- , laquo: "<<" , raquo: ">>" , laquo_space: "<< " , raquo_space: " >>" }
  smart_quotes: apos,apos,quot,quot
```

Comment: It looks like you can just add  `typographic_symbols: { hellip:..., mdash:--- }` in the `kramdown:` section in the `_config.yml` file. But there's no replacement for `"` and `'`.

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov Yes, hence the reference to the article on filter (https://www.sylvaindurand.org/improving-typography-on-jekyll/) in my answer, which addresses that.

Comment: It looks like, there's a better and easier way: `smart_quotes: apos,apos,quot,quot` (added like  `typographic_symbols`) in `_config.yml`.

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov Nice! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility